# Is TEmbeddedWB worth investigating?

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer

I try to use Google map API from a Delphi Application. I got a good start from my other question [Use Googlemap from my Delphi application ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558686/use-googlemap-from-my-delphi-application).
Now I found [TEmbeddedWB](http://www.bsalsa.com/intro.html) and I wonder if there are any advantages over the builtin TWebBrowser component. Both are interfaces to Internet Explorers DLL-files and seems to do similar things? I don't want to use more custom components than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The interface is much better than the twebbrowser one. there are also more events you can use. maybe important for you, you can modify the browsers security. this is necessary if javascript is disabled on the client machine. the twebbrowser is bound to the global ie settings.

i think using the tembeddedwb is an advantage.

Comment: Agree with this.  TEmbeddedWB is the best ready-to-use embedded browser I've found so far for Delphi Win32 development.

Answer (score 1):

I used TEmbeddedWB in one of my projects and found its impelentation worth using as it provides access to several events and methods which while not hard to implement yourself, are already present.

Answer (score 1):

TEmbeddedWB has good concept behind it, but it is developed in a horrible manner. Everything works at 50%, there are plenty of bugs, it is not tested nor documented.

So good luck!