# google maps non-web access

Tags: delphi, google-maps

I need to be able to access the Google Maps API from a non-web application. I see in Google Maps' FAQs that this is possible. However, I cannot find any reference to accessing the API from a PC-based application. Can someone point me in the right direction?

(I want to access the API from a Delphi application, if that helps.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before you spend more time on writing code, you should read the license terms very carefully and maybe consider using OpenStreetMap instead. Just saying...

Comment: My bottom line is that I need to capture a route on which a person drives, from start to stop. I need the street name, city, and state/province. Supposedly, the Google Maps API has a geodecoder which would give me that information, knowing the GPS coordinates.

Comment: It appears that nominatim from OpenStreetMap contains the data that I am looking for. Since I am a newbie at this, are there any examples of how to call nomiatim from within Delphi and interpret the xml results?

Answer (score 15):

Some time ago I wrote a series of articles about using the Google maps API v3 from Delphi, basically you need a [TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) component and load an HTML page with the JavaScript code to handle the [`Google Maps JavaScript API v3`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/). from here using functions like [IHTMLWindow2.execScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [MSHTML Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801967%28v=vs.85%29) you can interact with the JavaScript code and the Google Maps API responses from Delphi.

- [Using the Google Maps API V3 from Delphi – Part I Basic functionality](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/using-the-google-maps-api-v3-from-delphi-part-i-basic-functionality/)
- [Using the Google Maps API V3 from Delphi – Part II Styled Maps](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/using-the-google-maps-api-v3-from-delphi-part-ii-styled-maps/)
- [Using the Google Maps API V3 from Delphi – Part III Getting the latitude and longitude of a mouse click](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/using-the-google-maps-api-v3-from-delphi-%E2%80%93-part-iii-getting-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-mouse-click/)
- [Using Google maps (Static Maps) without TWebBrowser](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/using-google-maps-static-maps-without-twebbrowser/)

Also take a look to these projects

- [Delphimaps](http://code.google.com/p/delphimaps/)
- [GMLib – Google Maps Library](http://www.cadetill.com/?page_id=365)

Answer (score 5):

If you have serious plans in this direction:
**Forget about the Google Maps API, and use [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org) instead.**

Believe me, I've got hands-on experience with this. I've created countless interactive mapping websites and applications, and I've written code that wrap Google Maps functionality into Delphi components. You can find them on Google code: http://code.google.com/p/delphimaps/

You can also find some example application that I've made with an early version of these components here: [Use Googlemap from my Delphi application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558686/use-googlemap-from-my-delphi-application/559725#559725)

OpenLayers is much more versatile, it's completely open source, and it has a whole community behind it. It can even use Google Maps, but you can easily switch to OpenStreetMaps, Yahoo, Bing, or your own GIS system.

There are many examples online, and you're not tied to stupid rules that are imposed by Google. For example, if you want to use Google Maps via a secure (HTTPS) connection, you have to pay. I never directly use the Google Maps API anymore, and my GIS websites became much better since I started using OpenLayers.

Maybe one day I should wrap OpenLayers into Delphi components, but I now do most stuff in JavaScript instead, and only communicate with my Delphi app when it's really needed, so even with Delphi apps that contain a map, not much GIS stuff is done in Delphi.
That turns out to be easier to maintain.

..

Also, OpenLayers doesn't require any internet connection. It can run 100% in your offline browser. Google Maps requires you to have an internet connection, as it downloads parts of its code dynamically, and it always wants to download its maps from Google.

Comment: "I now do most stuff in JavaScript..." - you don't have to any more and you can stay with Pascal. Take a look at Smart Mobile Studio: http://op4js.optimalesystemer.no/about/

Comment: My bottom line is that I need to capture a route on which a person drives, from start to stop. I need the street name, city, and state/province. Can OpenLayers do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "capture a route", but if you need to turn coordinates into addresses, you can make use of the Google GeoCoder API. DelphiMaps wraps that for you, and there are two demo's on how to use it. DelphiMaps also wraps Google's routeplanner, and there's a demo for that too. This space is too small to give further explanations on it; ask a new question if you need help with that.

Comment: Yes -- turning coordinates into addresses will give me the street name, city, and state/province. The link to the DelphiMaps takes me to a deprecated download. Is there a more recent download somewhere else?

Comment: It's best to just use SVN. That way you'll automatically always get the latest version. But I've created a new zipfile with the sourcecode here: http://code.google.com/p/delphimaps/downloads/list

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a complete solution to use the Google Maps API with Delphi, I highly recommend the **Delphi Framework for Google Maps**. It enables to use **all** API functions **without** a single line of **HTML** or **JavaScript**.

For example:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Script(WebBrowser1) do
    if not APILoaded
      then LoadAPIAsync(InitMap);
end;

procedure TForm1.InitMap(Sender: TObject);
var
  MapOptions: TMapOptions;
begin
  with Sender as TScript do
  begin
    MapOptions:=New(Google.Maps.MapOptions);
    with MapOptions do
    begin
      Zoom:=8;
      Center:=New(Google.Maps.LatLng(-34.397,150.644));
      MapTypeID:=Google.Maps.MapTypeID.Roadmap;
    end;
    New(Google.Maps.Map(MapOptions));
  end;
end;
```

The route planner is also easily available. There are some demos.

Unfortunately, you must still download it currently from a [German forum](http://www.delphipraxis.net/157004-google-maps-ueber-com-component-object-model.html). A separate website is under construction. If there are problems with the registration or download, I can send an email with the framework.

Regards