# Delphi 7:How to get the distance between 2 addresses

Tags: delphi, maps, delphi-7, distance

I'm writing a program in Delphi for a (fake) courier company as a project. What I need, is the distance between the recipient and the couriers location. So I can work out what mode of transport should be used.

How can this be achieved? Via Google Maps?

Comment: If it's just a school project, use Google Maps. It's the easiest way to go IMHO.

Comment: This feels like a possible duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Google Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843029/google-maps-non-web-access) for details on how to use it